# How to replace a string with a variable value in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have the following function which takes a string `{{#x,y}}` and picks a random value between `x` and `y`:

```
$res = preg_replace_callback('/{{[#]([\w,]{1,})}}/', function ($match)  {
          $numbers = explode(',', $match[1]);
          shuffle($numbers);
          return isset($numbers[0]) ? $numbers[0] : '{#'.$match[0].'}';
        }, $res);
```

How can I modify this so that it does the following:

Take `{{$string, "val"}}` - if `$string` is empty or undefined, set it to `"val"`, otherwise set it to `$string`.

It should check to see if `$string` is already a variable that exists and is not empty, and then replace it with the true value of `$string`, otherwise use `val`

Example:

```
$string = "Hello";
$res = 'This is a test {{$string, "Ok"}}';

//call function

echo $res // This is a test Hello
```

Another Example:

```
$res = 'This is a test {{$string, "Ok"}}';

//call function

echo $res // This is a test Ok
```

Comment: Here’s a quick gist that might help you, scope is the biggest pain. You can use `$$` to reference a variable variable. https://3v4l.org/Kg8Yh#v8.1.8

Comment: You are trying to match a `#` sign with `{{[#]` but that is not in the example data correct?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Not correct, that function can just be used to build this new one since the principles are similar. The aim is to achieve it with `$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried the examples you provided with this block of code and it worked.

```
<?php
$string = "Hello";
$subject  = 'This is a test {{$string, "Ok"}}';

$varsInContext = get_defined_vars();
var_dump(parseText($subject, $varsInContext)); //This is a test Hello

function parseText(string $completeString, array $varsInContext):string {
    
    $pattern = '/(?<blockTextToReplace>{{\$(?<variableToEval>.+),\s?"(?<fallbackValue>[\w\d]+)"}})/';
    preg_match($pattern,$completeString,$matches);    
    
    
    if(!empty($matches)){
        $variableToEval = $matches['variableToEval'];
        $fallbackValue = $matches['fallbackValue'];
        $finalValue = !empty($varsInContext[$variableToEval]) ? $varsInContext[$variableToEval] : $fallbackValue;
        
        $blockTextToReplace = $matches['blockTextToReplace'];
        $finalText = str_replace($blockTextToReplace, $finalValue, $completeString);
        
        return $finalText;
    }
    
    return $completeString;
}
```

Consider that it uses **all the variables in the context**, if the variable provided in the "subject" is going to be available in the same scope, you may use variable variable to optimize the process

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to get this to work when there are multiple instances of `{{$var, "val"}}` in the string - e.g. `$subject = 'hello {{$string, "Ok"}} another example {{$anotherString, "Value"}}'`